# updating from python 2 to python 3

Tags: python, python-2to3

I'm updating a script written in python 2 to python 3 which I'm learning while trying to use. this wxpython controlled LED class is causing an error: (TypeError: Expected a list of bytes objects.) I believe the problem stems from this list

```
xpm = ['17 17 5 1', # width height ncolors chars_per_pixel
        '0 c %s' % corner_color.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX).encode('ascii'),
        'X c %s' % base_color.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX).encode('ascii'),
        '- c %s' % light_color.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX).encode('ascii'),
        '= c %s' % shadow_color.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX).encode('ascii'),
        '* c %s' % highlight_color.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX).encode('ascii')]

xpm += [s.strip() for s in ascii_led.splitlines()]

self.bmp = wx.Bitmap(xpm)
```

OG code came from the code below, which is from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/533125-wxpython-led-control/

```
# Based on C++ code by Thomas Monjalon
# Developed by Daniel Eloff on 14/9/07

import wx

def change_intensity(color, fac):
    rgb = [color.Red(), color.Green(), color.Blue()]
    for i, intensity in enumerate(rgb):
        rgb[i] = min(int(round(intensity*fac, 0)), 255)

    return wx.Color(*rgb)    

class LED(wx.Control):
    def __init__(self, parent, id=-1, colors=[wx.Colour(220, 10, 10), wx.Colour(250, 200, 0), wx.Colour(10, 220, 10)],
                 pos=(-1,-1), style=wx.NO_BORDER):
        size = (17, 17)
        wx.Control.__init__(self, parent, id, pos, size, style)
        self.MinSize = size

        self._colors = colors
        self._state = -1
        self.SetState(0)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint, self)

    def SetState(self, i):
        if i < 0:
            raise ValueError, 'Cannot have a negative state value.'
        elif i >= len(self._colors):
            raise IndexError, 'There is no state with an index of %d.' % i
        elif i == self._state:
            return

        self._state = i
        base_color = self._colors[i]
        light_color = change_intensity(base_color, 1.15)
        shadow_color = change_intensity(base_color, 1.07)
        highlight_color = change_intensity(base_color, 1.25)

        ascii_led = '''
        000000-----000000      
        0000---------0000
        000-----------000
        00-----XXX----=00
        0----XX**XXX-===0
        0---X***XXXXX===0
        ----X**XXXXXX====
        ---X**XXXXXXXX===
        ---XXXXXXXXXXX===
        ---XXXXXXXXXXX===
        ----XXXXXXXXX====
        0---XXXXXXXXX===0
        0---=XXXXXXX====0
        00=====XXX=====00
        000===========000
        0000=========0000
        000000=====000000
        '''.strip()

        xpm = ['17 17 5 1', # width height ncolors chars_per_pixel
               '0 c None', 
               'X c %s' % base_color.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX).encode('ascii'),
               '- c %s' % light_color.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX).encode('ascii'),
               '= c %s' % shadow_color.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX).encode('ascii'),
               '* c %s' % highlight_color.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX).encode('ascii')]

        xpm += [s.strip() for s in ascii_led.splitlines()]

        self.bmp = wx.BitmapFromXPMData(xpm)

        self.Refresh()

    def GetState(self):
        return self._state

    State = property(GetState, SetState)

    def OnPaint(self, e):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        dc.DrawBitmap(self.bmp, 0, 0, True)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask]. What's your question? Are you aware that [Python 2 and 3 handle strings totally differently](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#text-vs-data-instead-of-unicode-vs-8-bit)? Please [edit] the question to have a descriptive title, and to clarify what you're asking. LMK when you do and I'll undo my downvote.

Comment: My bad, obviously you're asking how to fix it. You should still set a better title though.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging? Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.

Answer (score 2):

`bytes` and `str` were synonyms in Python 2 but have become incompatible types in Python 3. The constructor for `wx.Bitmap` expects a list of bytes, so you should make sure that every item in the list you pass to it is a `bytes` object by either using bytes literals or encoding strings into bytes:

```
xpm = [b'17 17 5 1', # width height ncolors chars_per_pixel
        b'0 c %s' % corner_color.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX).encode('ascii'),
        b'X c %s' % base_color.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX).encode('ascii'),
        b'- c %s' % light_color.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX).encode('ascii'),
        b'= c %s' % shadow_color.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX).encode('ascii'),
        b'* c %s' % highlight_color.GetAsString(wx.C2S_HTML_SYNTAX).encode('ascii')]

xpm += [s.strip().encode('ascii') for s in ascii_led.splitlines()]
```

Comment: hey thanks for the advice how might I accomplish that? I started learning python last week so I'm struggling a bit.

Comment: You're welcome. Have you tried the code example I included above? Note the added `b` prefix to each string literal to make it a bytes literal, and the added call to `encode` in the last line.

Comment: I had not noticed the difference, I just tried it and it did not change the error it still says It expects a list of bytes. thank you for your help though

Answer (score 0):

The doc on `wx` isn't very clear on how exactly it wants this input to be formatted, but you can try just encoding each of your `str`s in the default `utf-8` before passing the list to the `Bitmap` constructor:

```
self.bmp = wx.Bitmap([s.encode() for s in xpm])
```

Comment: Thank for trying to help I tried that and it caused a system error which tossed a whole error pop up which is more than my attempts got so cool. the window said, "XPM: malformed colour definition '0 c b#808080' ' at line 1!

Answer (score 0):

Bytes objects are different in Python 3. See [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes-objects) page.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the bytes string into list() to convert back:

```
list(bytes(xpm))
```

Comment: Thank you for the help it did not work it caused "TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"